# Lambda function returning null parameters when receiving Kafka event

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, aws-lambda, avro

I am developing a lambda function that receives events from a Kafka connector and Avro schema but when invoked, it is returning null values ​​as per the log below:

```
Event received: KafkaEvent(records=null, eventSource=null, eventSourceArn=null, bootstrapServers=null)
```

Handler Class:

```
public class Handler implements RequestHandler<KafkaEvent, String> {

    private final ManagerUseCase useCase;

    public Handler() {
        this.useCase = new ManagerUseCase ();
    }

    public Handler(ManagerUseCase useCase) {
        this.useCase = useCase;
    }

    @Override
    public String handleRequest(KafkaEvent event, Context context) {
        out.println("Event received: " + event);

        if (event == null) {
            out.println("Null event!");
            return "Processing not completed!";
        }

        if (event.getRecords() == null) {
            out.println("Null record list!");
            return "Processing not completed!";
        }

        if (event.getRecords().isEmpty() || event.getRecords().values().stream().anyMatch(List::isEmpty)) {
            out.println("Event without registrations!");
            return "Processing not completed!";
        }

        event.getRecords().values().stream()
                .flatMap(List::stream)
                .forEach(kafkaEventRecord -> useCase.processarEventoHandler(kafkaEventRecord.getValue()));

        return "Processing completed!";
    }
}
```

Observation:
I'm using Avro schema which is processed in the UseCase class and it is deserialized using Decoder (I'll leave the method below for you to see) and I'm using Java 17.

```
private ComandEventClients deserializeAvro(String avro) throws IOException {
        DatumReader<ComandEventClients> reader = new SpecificDatumReader<>(ComandEventClients.class);
        Decoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().jsonDecoder(ComandEventClients.getClassSchema(), avro);
        log.info("Deserializing message: {}", avro);
        return reader.read(null, decoder);
    }
```

Avro stub: **ComandEventClients**

Does anyone know what can it be?
Thanks in advance!